# How can one prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions to linear differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof

It is a theorem (I think) that the equation:

> $$\mathbf{x}'(t) = A(t)\mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{b}(t); \qquad \qquad \mathbf{x}(t_0) = \mathbf{x}_0$$

Has a unique global solution for any matrix $A(t)$ and vector $\mathbf{b}(t)$ whose entries are continuous functions of $t$.

My question is: Is there a relatively simple proof of existence and uniqueness? (By relatively simple, I mean not applying Picard-Lindelof).

In the case that $A$ is a constant matrix, one has a fairly easy proof using the matrix exponential. In the general case, perhaps one could use a time-ordered matrix exponential? Or perhaps there is a nice inductive proof based on the size of $A$?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will wind up essentially imitating the proof of Picard-Lindelof if you do not just quote it. Also, I doubt the solution is truly global, what happens when $ A $ blows up?

Comment: @Ian Yes, the solution is global.   Grönwall's inequality can be useful.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I disagree. Try $A(t)=t^2 I$ and $b(t) \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Ian The solution will be $t^3/3 I$ :) which is of course global.

Comment: @Artem Oh, my bad, I didn't think about the fact that it is just $A(t)$, not $A(t,x)$. Yes in this case the solution is indeed global.